# Android: background invisible service

Tags: java, android, security

I did not find answer for my question in the Internet that why want ask here. Theoretical question preparing for creating new Android app:

1) Purpose: create app thats logs events on device and saves it or on device or on server(optional). Logs like: application runs, errors, or traffic rate etc...

Also app can be used for monitoring if some one used your device.

2) Requirements: running in background like service but invisible for user or with minimum visibility.

Question: how to make app with minimum visibility? How set app to be invisible in app list or services list?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve your goal without rooting. To ensure that your application doesn't get killed you need a Service with setForeground() property set. And a Service needs to be registered by the Android system, thus it will always appear in the running services list. You can try to control access to that list though, with a locker of some sort.

Comment: OK, to be visible in service list thats ok, but this is an app and how to make it invisible in app list after installation?

Comment: If the Android people do have an API that allows apps to do this, please let us know so that I can switch to iPhone.  And write Android and tell them why.